# Help required to form Json string in Javascript

Tags: string, json

Hi i have to create a json sting in javascript like this

```
{widget_list:[{widget_id:1,new_position:2},{widget_id:2,new_position:3},  .  .  .]}
```

using json.org library. Function i am using of this library is

> var json_text =
>   JSON.stringify(uploaded, "", "");

Which creates a perfect json string i am able to generate when there is a no array

```
function uploaded()
{

}
var uploaded = new Uploaded();
uploaded.widget_id = 1;
uploaded.new_position = 2;
var json_text = JSON.stringify(uploaded, "", "");
```

when u alert json_text u will get {"widget_id":1,"new_position":2} requirment is just download a file json2.js from json.org for javascript and include it.

so please help some logic issue i am unable to create....
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uploaded = {};
var a = [];

uploaded.widget_id = 1;
uploaded.new_position = 2;
a[0] = uploaded;

uploaded.widget_id = 2;
uploaded.new_position = 3;
a[1] = uploaded;
uploaded_new = {}
uploaded_new.widget_list = a
alert( JSON.stringify(uploaded_new, "", ""));
```

alert will give

```
{"widget_list":[{"widget_id":2,"new_position":3},{"widget_id":2,"new_position":3}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this looking for a similar solution, in that it helped. But you need to re-initialize the "uploaded" object, otherwise it over-writes the existing values.

So, with that slight modification, it would be

```
uploaded = {};
var a = [];

uploaded.widget_id = 1;
uploaded.new_position = 2;
a[0] = uploaded;

**uploaded = {};**

uploaded.widget_id = 2;
uploaded.new_position = 3;
a[1] = uploaded;
uploaded_new = {}
uploaded_new.widget_list = a
alert( JSON.stringify(uploaded_new, "", ""));
```